# Reference recommendation in dynamical system

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I need a good book that is self-study in dynamical system. I have the book "Geometric Theory of Dynamical Systems" by Jacob Palis but it is difficult and is not a self-study book. I need a book that covering the content (*) of Palis's book and being a self-study book. Thank you in advance.

(*) Local Stability, Kupka-Smale Theorem and Genericity and Stability of Morse-Smale Vector Fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [Anosov & Arnold's - Dynamical Systems I](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540170006), and found it pretty nice.

Maybe [Brin & Stuck - Introduction to Dynamical Systems](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/introduction-dynamical-systems-1) is more friendly but I doubt they cover all of Palis' book content.